# Question from Duffie and Kan (1996)

Tags: yield-curve, papers

Going through [Duffie and Kan (1996)](https://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/DuffieKan1996.pdf) I came up with a question.

After Eq. $(3.4)$ the claim the following:

> By $(2.4)$, we also know that $\mathcal{D} F (X_t, t) - R(X_t) F(X_t, t) = 0$. Since $F$ is strictly positive valued, from $(3.4)$ we have [...].

and then they equate what they claim together with equation $(3.4)$ to get equation $(3.5)$.

I don't see how to get that $\mathcal{D} F (X_t, t) - R(X_t) F(X_t, t) = 0$ from equation $(2.4)$. Eq. $(2.4)$ is just the definition of a zero-coupon bond as the expectation of the exponential compounding of the instantaneous rate (please see [the paper](https://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/DuffieKan1996.pdf) for the exact formula). Does someone know how to proceed to prove it? From how it is stated in the article I guess that it must be obvious somehow, however, I can't see a clear path to prove it.

---

**Edit:** As Kurt G. mentioned, my question can be easily solved using the Feynman-Kac formula. The FK formula tells us that an unknown function $u:\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ whose evolution is described by the PDE

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -V(x,t) u(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0, $$

defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in [0, T]$ and subject to the terminal condition $u(x,T)=\psi(x)$, has a solution that can be written as a conditional expectation as follows:

$$u(x,t) = E^Q\left[ \int_t^T e^{-  \int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}f(X_r,r)dr + e^{-\int_t^T V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\psi(X_T) \,\Bigg|\, X_t=x \right] .$$

Taking the inverse path, i.e. starting from the conditional expectation, where in the case of the formula appearing in Duffie and Kan we have $f(x,t) = 0 $ and $\psi(X_T) = 1$, we can see that the PDE that $u(x,t)$ must satisfy corresponds to:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -V(x,t) u(x,t) = 0, $$

where $\mathcal{D} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(x,t) $.

Comment: This is  a well-known theorem of Feynman and Kac. See for example Karatzas & Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.*

Comment: Thanks Kurt! That's it. I knew I was missing something simple from the way that was written in the article.